# Java / Kotlin equivalent of Swift [String : [String : Any]]

Tags: java, android, swift, dictionary, kotlin

What is the equivalent of `[String : [String : Any]]` from Swift in Kotlin or Java language?

I need to retrieve from database a structure that looks like this:

```
Key:
    Key : Value
    Key : Value
    Key : Value
Key :
    Key : Value
    Key : Value
    Key : Value
```

Comment: retrieve  from DB to app in this format use json

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This structure can be represented by a `Map<String, Map<String, Any>>`. The Kotlin code for creating such a type:

```
val fromDb: Map<String, Map<String, Any>> = mapOf(
    "Key1" to mapOf("KeyA" to "Value", "KeyB" to "Value"),
    "Key2" to mapOf("KeyC" to "Value", "KeyD" to "Value")
)
```

In Java, as of JDK 9, it can be expressed like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> fromDb = Map.of(
    "Key1", Map.of("KeyA", "Value", "KeyB", "Value"),
    "Key2", Map.of("KeyC", "Value", "KeyD", "Value")
);
```

Note that the `Any` type in Kotlin is basically the same as `Object` in Java.